# Two views ontop of eachother, but only show one?

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton and a TextView of the same size width and height inside of a RelativeView. By default, the TextView is disabled and the ImageButton is enabled. However, I am unable to click on the ImageButton under these circumstances.

When I enable the TextView and disable the ImageButton, I CAN click the TextView however. I think this is because it is under the ImageButton in the XML.

Does anyone know how I can get this sort of "toggling" functionality where both items are of the same size ontop of eachother, but only one is clickable at a time?

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/pp_note_1"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"/>

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:id="@+id/pp_autonote_1"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" />


            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You could make your life easy and use a ViewSwitcher. Or instead of disabling try to set the visibility to GONE.

Comment: @ElDuderino Hm never heard of a ViewSwitcher, I can look into this. Also, would changing the visibility let me use the background one?

Comment: If you set the visibility of the ImageButton to GONE, the background of the ImageButton will not be shown anymore. If you need the background for both views, set it to the RelativeLayout or to the ViewSwitcher should you use it. You can of course also set it to the TextView, so both views have the background.

Comment: @ElDuderino I put them both in a ViewSwitcher and initially I only see the ImageButton but I can't click on it. Is that because there some invisible TextView infront of it?

Comment: I just added a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to

```
public void setFocusable (boolean focusable)
public void setFocusableInTouchMode (boolean focusableInTouchMode)
public void setClickable (boolean clickable)
```

[View](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of switching two views with a ViewSwitcher :

viewswitcher.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/viewSwitcher"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="96dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</ViewSwitcher>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity's onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewswitcher);

    final ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher);
    final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewSwitcher.showNext();
        }
    });
}
```

To animate the transition, use viewPager.setInAnimation() and .setOutAnimation().

Comment: I realized a ViewSwitcher will not work for me, because this toggle is a setting, so when the app launches again, I check the saved preference and enable/disable one accordingly, which I cannot do with ViewSwitcher (only showNext and showPrevious). I still can't figure out how to make this work.

Comment: Well, instead of enable/disable, just do viewPager.showNext() or don't do it. That way you either show the ImageButton or the TextView. You can use viewPager.reset() to ... reset everything. So you can start from zero.

Comment: I dont understand why enabling and disabling wont work. It still wont let me use whichever one is higher in the xml.

Comment: I believe you shouldn't use enable/disable if you just want to change visibility. It is rather used for enabling/disabling input handling I think.